# Openshift monitoring - spring , display pods

Tags: java, json, spring, openshift

Hey everyone:D I'd like to get json with lists of pods from openshift. I'm using :

`Node[] nodes = template.getForObject("[url_address]/api/v1/nodes", Node[].class);`

but its need authentication, so how to solve this problemm. Any idea??

Comment: Can you add more detail. What's your use case? You are running a Java application using the Java client? Is this a Pod running on OpenShift or externally?

Answer (score 0):

The authorization requires a valid bearer token, default kubernetes client library should use service account mounted to pod to attempt to authenticate properly. It is likely that you either do not use the client lib that does that for you or have no proper serviceaccount bound to the pod (or SA has no access granted to required resources).

For that you may want to just add the access rights to the default account for this project.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/admin_solutions/user_role_mgmt.html

Comment: Answer is correct but I'm not sure if they are running the client within the cluster?